# SQLSTATE[08S01]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init]

Tags: php, sql-server, ssl, redhat, odbc-sql-server-driver

It's a new experience for me, using Laravel with SQL Server.

My issue is, some of it shows this error message `SQLSTATE[08S01]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server]SSL Provider: [error:140E0197:SSL routines:SSL_shutdown:shutdown while in init]` when `INSERT` or `UPDATE` the data. It's happened randomly.

Here's my connection string on Laravel.

[image]

Please tell me, how to resolve this issue.

Comment: That error is coming from the OpenSSL library because the SSL_shutdown() method was called while SSL_in_init() returns true. If it only happens intermittently I'd recommend checking any NICs, switches and routers on the intermediate path to see if they're getting overloaded. If you're dealing with vNICs on virtualized machines also check that the correct vNIC and drivers are installed appropriate to each guest operating system version.

Comment: I am having the same issue right now. Ubuntu with Open SSL 3.0.2 and php 8.1.15, odbc 18, unixodbc 2.3.11.

Comment: Not intermittent, but only on certain queries. Happens every time. Cannot replicate on Mac. Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, I don't know how to check NICs or vNICs.
But, The issues happened only to the new app servers.
that means some app servers are working fine.